# Why do I see an "x" tick mark next to a few dependencies of node when I use brew info node?

Tags: node.js, homebrew

I am new to using Homebrew to manage and install packages. I installed node using nvm which was installed using the command `brew install nvm`. I then used `brew info node` and this came up:

```
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✘, python@3.9 ✘
Required: brotli ✔, c-ares ✔, icu4c ✘, libuv ✔, nghttp2 ✔, openssl@1.1 ✔
```

I am assuming that this indicates whether that package is installed or not. However, as it is listed as required, how is it that it wasn't installed along with the rest of the dependencies? Can someone explain to me what is happening? In the event that this is an issue I should fix, what steps do I need to take?

Comment: Great news I figured it out. it turns out that it was an outdated package and that I had to upgrade it with brew upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

`nvm` and `node` are two different packages. You installed `nvm` but not `node`, so there’s nothing wrong in that `node`’s dependencies are not installed.